# How to make inline div content not splitted in line break

Tags: html, css

I have a message div and a date font inside.

[image]

However, if the content of the message is long, the date is being splitted in line break. What I want to do is, if there is no space for date, it should be all in the next line instead of split.

css

```css
.message {
    width:500px;
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
    white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap; /* Newer versions of Chrome/Safari*/
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
    position:relative;
}
    
.messagecontent {
    display: inline-block;
}
    
.date {
    font-size:11px;
    color:#999;
    padding-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div class="message">
  <div class="messagecontent"></div>
  <font class="date"></div>
</div>
```

What is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: Just add `white-space: nowrap;` , may be it can solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the date will need to be included in the messagecontent div. code:

```
<div class="message">
    <div class="messagecontent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi mollis felis eget accumsan aliquet. Mauris semper id tortor et tristique. Cras mi ante, euismod in luctus id, hendrerit vel elit.<div class="date">13:12</div></div>
</div>
```

and set to inline-block:

```
.date {
    font-size:11px;
    color:#999;
    padding-left:5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the `word-break` and `word-wrap` properties on the `.date` class:

```
.date {
  word-wrap: normal;
  word-break: normal;
}
```